# How to connect moodle server running Ubuntu server to outside world?

Tags: networking, server, dns, ip, moodle

I work at a school where we have our internet distributed through three APs (it's a small school). I have connected one computer to the switch as my Moodle server. Assigned IP for that computer is, of course, 192.168.... I'd like to access my Moodle from outside our network.

Someone told me I should set DNS for that IP.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) helps you with getting IP address from a textual domain name but it cannot help with IP address visibility.

You need to configure [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on your router(s) to forward requests from outside internet to your server. One of the easiest ways to achieve this is [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).